# Recursivity missing for loop case in java

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion

my goal is to associate all team members to teamleaders but hierarchically. eg : Bill is a top team leader, John and Alice are one level down, Mary is one level down to John and Alice,etc...

```
Team leader   Team members
=========      ==========
Bob           ""
Marry        Bob
John         Marry
Alice        Marry
Bill         John,Alice
```

So I use

```
final static SetMultimap<String, String> teamMap = HashMultimap
    .create();
```

and I want to get for each Team leader the full team members list he leads

```
eg : For Alice as a Team Leader, her full team members list is Marry, Bob. 
     For Bill as a Team Leader, his full team members list is John, Alice, Marry, Bob
```

Since recursivity seems to answer to my problem, I use this

```
   public static List<String> getTeamMembers(String teamLeader) {

    List<String> teamMembers = teamMembersMap.get(teamLeader);
    fullTeamMembers.addAll(teamMembers);

    for (String teamMember : teamMembers) {
        if (teamMember.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
**// if teamMember is John go to Marry then Bob and return recursively 
// without treating Alice loop!**
        return fullTeamMembers;
        } else {
        return getTeamMembers(teamMember);
        }
    }
**// compiler error otherwise force to return something here
// maybe in case teamMembers is empty****
    return null;

    }
```

And my call

```
for (String teamLeader : teamMembersMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("********************************");
    System.out.println("**************teamLeader :" + teamLeader);
    fullTeamMembers.clear();
    List<String> fullTeamMembers = getTeamMembers(teamLeader);
    teamMembersMap.putAll(teamLeader, fullTeamMembers);

}
```

But I am stucked on the two point in comment in the code : the loop issue and the return compiler error. Any Help is welcomed to solve this problem in a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it tells you to put a `return` statement there. Your `teamMembers` could be empty or even NULL. Other than a few missing null/empty checks, there is nothing wrong with your code.

If you really want an improvement and null safety, here's my suggestion:

```
public static List<String> getTeamMembers(final String teamLeader) 
{
     final List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(); // fullTeamMembers
     final List<String> teamMembers = teamMembersMap.get(teamLeader); // Can be NULL or empty

     if (teamMembers == null || teamMembers.isEmpty())
          return result; // Return empty array

     // Else, carry on
     result.addAll(teamMembers);

     for (String teamMember : result) 
          if ( !teamMember.equalsIgnoreCase("") ) 
               return getTeamMembers(teamMember); // Go recursively if not ""

     // Return result from map
     return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's improving :-) Nevertheless for : 
for (String teamMember : teamMembers) it goes only in first 

teamMember and return. 
eg : List<String> fullTeamMembers = getTeamMembers("Bill");
    give me                

teamMember : John of teamMembers[John, Alice]
teamMember : Marry of teamMembers[Marry]
teamMember : Bob of teamMembers[Bob]
teamMember :  of teamMembers[]
so Alice case is complitly ignore computed in the for statement.
Any  idea?